# Go through array based on previous value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue']`.

I want to change the background color of my website using these colors. But I don't want to just take a random color from this array. I want to iterate it in order.

So if I get the background color of my website with `getBgColor()` and it prints `red`, then I want a function `setBgColor(currentColor)` to print `yellow`. How do I do this?

I guess I should do something like

```
function setBgColor(currentColor) {
  var array = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'];

  newColor = array[array.indexOf(currentColor) + 1];
}
```

but is this the right approach? And how do I make sure that I go from blue to green and thus not exceeding the length of the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [modulo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) `%` with the length of the array.

```
function setBgColor(currentColor) {
    var array = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
        newColor = array[(array.indexOf(currentColor) + 1) % array.length ];
    // set the new color
    // ...
}
```

Comment: nice answer - **newColor** needs to be returned

Answer (score 0):

Just include a conditional in your number to add:

```
var array = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'],
    last_index = array.length - 1,
    thisIndex = array.indexOf(currentColor);

return array[thisIndex + (thisIndex !== last_index ? 1 : (-1 * last_index))];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable that contains the current index, rather than searching for the color in the array. Use modular arithmetic to increment the index, wrapping around at the array size.

```
var colorIndex = 0;
var colorArray = ['green', 'red', 'yellow', 'blue'];

function setBgColor() {
    colorIndex = (colorIndex + 1) % array.length;
    return colorArray[colorIndex];
}
```